# How to fix placeholder text within the input in material ui text field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, textfield

I am using material ui text field.

The current behavior of the text field is, on focus the placeholder goes on top of the text field.

[image: Current behavior]

I don't want it to go on top of the text field I want it to be within text field and disappear once the user starts typing as below.

[image: Before typing] [image: After typing]

I tried giving `disableAnimation: true` in `InputLabelProps`. But that isn't working. What can I do to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding an empty label to the TextField. This way the placeholder will not move up when you start editing, because the place of the label is 'occupied'.

```js
<TextField
  id="standard-full-width"
  label=""
  placeholder="Placeholder"
/>
```